# Timeout before emulator launches the app , and instrumentationProcess terminated due to receipt of signal null

Tags: detox

When I run detox test, my app is getting installed in the android emulator, and then getting error :

**instrumentationProcess terminated due to receipt of signal null**

1) "before all" hook

0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

1)  "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

child_process.js:635
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration android.emu.debug --loglevel verbose
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:592:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:632:13)
    at runMocha (/Users/housing/housing-app/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:56:6)
    at Object. (/Users/housing/housing-app/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:36:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)

I am using : **Detox version - 5.10.0 , 
react-native  - 0.44.0 ,  Node - v8.6.0 , Device - android emulator , macOS - Sierra**

How i can resolve this? Any suggestions...

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear what your question is.

Comment: Hi Pascal, i have edited the question, and tried to explain the issue i am facing, please check. Should i add more information...?

Comment: I just found, 
This issue is already reported on Github : https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/407

Comment: And now fixed in https://github.com/wix/detox/pull/434

Comment: @Rotemmiz i set up Detox from scratch for ReactNative app, but still facing the Timeout error. I have mentioned in detail here;

https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/524

Need your guidance to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code defect is addressed by https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/407